# RODBC-Package: Select rows in a database table that match values in an R-vector

Tags: r, join, where-clause, rodbc

I have list of about 150'000 ID-numbers in a R-vector (ids) and a big data base table (dbo.datafromhell) with columnnames "IDnr", "V1" and "V2" and about 1.6 Mio rows.

I'd like to select rows from dbo.datafromhell with ID-numbers (IDnr) that match to the values in "ids"

```
ids <- c(1,2,3,4) #in real: 150'000 id-numbers
```

I tried the following query with a "where-in-list"-statement, but it used to much resources and terminated with an error:

```
df <- sqlQuery(mycon, paste("SELECT * FROM dbo.datafromhell WHERE IDnr IN (",paste(ids,sep="",collapse=","),")"))
```

I suppose my value list (ids) is to big for a "where-in-list"-statement.

At the end I'd like a data frame that contains only rows with matching IDs between the value list and the data base table:

```
 IDnr V1    V2
    1  A  TRUE
    2  B FALSE
    3  C  TRUE
    4  D FALSE

#in real: about 150'000 rows (different IDnr)
```

I also tried to write a sqlQuery that joins the data base table directly to my value list. but I couldn't figure it out.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fasted option is to save the 150.000 ID's to a staging table in the database and then create a query on both tables.

Comment: thanks for your input! a good idea, but as I'm not provided with the rights to alter the database, this is not an option

Comment: I use the technique often with even larger sets ( a few million id's). You only need rights to empty the staging table and write the new id's into it. It should be possible to convince the DBA to allow this. If not, then you are stuck with the solution of @nicola.

Answer (score 1):

A (slow) work-around is to split your `ids` into chunks of manageable size, run a query for each chunk and `rbind` all the results. Something like this:

```
#define how big is manageable
manSize<-1000
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(split(ids,seq_along(ids)%/%manSize), 
              function(x) sqlQuery(mycon, paste("SELECT * FROM dbo.datafromhell WHERE IDnr IN (",paste(x,sep="",collapse=","),")"))))
```